# division of a task on multiple thread with ScheduledTaskRegistrar

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I have a List of object Feed that I load from the database, then i use these objects to access to internet with a property UrlFeed and do some work to get items from each Feed, the probleme is I use one thread and output time depends on the size of the List so output time will increase if the list become larger. I want to use multiple threads and reduce this output time.I want to know how to  divide this task to multiple threads, or how to decrease the output time?

I use Spring Boot and worked with ScheduledTaskRegistrar to schedule the task periodically
this is my config class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApp implements SchedulingConfigurer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}

@AutoWired
TaskConfig tC;


@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(20);
}

@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {

    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());

    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override 
                public void run() {

                    for(Feed f : getListFeed()){

                          accessToFeedAndDoSomeWork(f.getUrlFeed);
                    }


                    }
                }, 
            new Trigger() {

                    @Override
                    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                        Calendar nextExecutionTime =  new GregorianCalendar();
                        Date lastActualExecutionTime = triggerContext.lastActualExecutionTime();
                        nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());
                        nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tC.getRate);
                        return nextExecutionTime.getTime();
                    }
                });



}
}
```

is there a solution with ScheduledTaskRegistrar, Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tryed to create a task by url, instead of one task which iterate on the urls ?

Comment: If I do so i'll end with a lot of tasks because it depends on the number of urls so 200 url will generate 200 tasks and I think it's a lot

Comment: no, your thread pool is bounded : you'll have 200 tasks, but only 20 threads (20 in your code)

Comment: Ah ok now I understand so the rest of tasks will wait their turn to be executed I am right ?

Comment: It works thanks now jérémie if I want to stop tasks should I pass a null value to  
ionTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tC.getRate);